# While using dagger 2 : e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: void

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am using dagger2 and after adding some view model injection code, I get this error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: void
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacTypes.getDeclaredType0(JavacTypes.java:252)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacTypes.getDeclaredType(JavacTypes.java:222)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.langmodel.DaggerTypes.getDeclaredType(DaggerTypes.java:345)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindsTypeChecker.desiredAssignableType(BindsTypeChecker.java:71)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindsTypeChecker.isAssignable(BindsTypeChecker.java:56)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindsMethodValidator$Validator.checkParameter(BindsMethodValidator.java:92)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingMethodValidator$MethodValidator.checkParameters(BindingMethodValidator.java:209)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindsMethodValidator$Validator.checkParameters(BindsMethodValidator.java:77)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingMethodValidator$MethodValidator.checkAdditionalProperties(BindingMethodValidator.java:144)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingElementValidator$ElementValidator.validate(BindingElementValidator.java:145)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingElementValidator$ElementValidator.access$000(BindingElementValidator.java:129)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingElementValidator.validateUncached(BindingElementValidator.java:78)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.Util.reentrantComputeIfAbsent(Util.java:93)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.BindingElementValidator.validate(BindingElementValidator.java:74)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.AnyBindingMethodValidator.validateUncached(AnyBindingMethodValidator.java:99)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.Util.reentrantComputeIfAbsent(Util.java:93)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.AnyBindingMethodValidator.validate(AnyBindingMethodValidator.java:74)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleValidator.validateUncached(ModuleValidator.java:189)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleValidator.lambda$validate$0(ModuleValidator.java:169)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.Util.reentrantComputeIfAbsent(Util.java:93)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleValidator.validate(ModuleValidator.java:169)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleValidator.validate(ModuleValidator.java:163)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleProcessingStep.process(ModuleProcessingStep.java:98)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleProcessingStep.process(ModuleProcessingStep.java:47)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.lambda$process$0(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:51)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.forEach(RegularImmutableMap.java:185)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.TypeCheckingProcessingStep.process(TypeCheckingProcessingStep.java:48)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleProcessingStep.process(ModuleProcessingStep.java:89)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleProcessingStep.process(ModuleProcessingStep.java:47)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerStatisticsCollectingProcessingStep.process(DaggerStatisticsCollectingProcessingStep.java:52)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:330)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:230)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:188)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:555)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:546)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:164)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1558)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I don't know much about it, why this occurred, but also tried some solution and updating versions of `kotlin` and dagger2 but didn't work.

Let me know if something else is needed to put in the code.

Answer (score 10):

I just suffered through this exact error. Make sure that you're returning a `ViewModel` from your module function (provides or binds) e.g.

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(AuthenticationViewModel::class)
abstract fun bindsAuthViewModel(authViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel) :ViewModel
```

I'm writing kotlin for the first time in a while and I forgot to add the `:ViewModel` to return the dependency that'll get injected wherever.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In a problem similar to the one described in @bibangamba 's answer, it can also happen when using `dagger.android` and not returning the `AndroidInjector.Factory<*>` type for the injector factory's binding function declaration:

```
@Module(subcomponents = [
    ChatComponent::class
])
interface ChatModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(ChatFragment::class)
    abstract fun bindChatFragmentInjectorFactory(
        factory: ChatComponent.Factory
    ): AndroidInjector.Factory<*>
}
```